Why can $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_{n}$ be expressed in $a_n=\alpha\cdot3^n+\beta\cdot2^n$?
Based on some other posts in this site, i got that
$$a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_{n}$$  can be expressed by finding the roots of $x^2=5x-6$, which are $x={2, 3}$.
Then, making the general solution $$a_n=\alpha\cdot3^n+\beta\cdot2^n$$
I don't quite understand the process behind this.
Can someone help me explain in simple terms please?
Thank you in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

You can find it all here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients

Thank you for the info! @MartinR

"by finding the factors" $\to$ "by finding the roots".

It begins with the presumption that $a_n=r^n$ for some $r$. With this assumption, we may replace each $a_k$ with $r^k$, letting us go from this:
$$a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_n$$
To this:
$$r^{n+2}=5r^{n+1}-6r^n$$
Dividing everything by $r^n$ yields:
$$r^2=5r-6$$
This has two solutions, $r=2$ or $r=3$. Since we started with the assumption that $a_n=r^n$ and we found two valid solutions for $r$, we include both of them, leading us to conclude:
$$a_n= \alpha \cdot 2^n + \beta \cdot 3^n$$
The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ account for the initial conditions of the recurrence; i.e. they are chosen so that $\alpha+\beta=a_0$ and $\alpha \cdot 2 + \beta \cdot 3=a_1$. Then it is ensured that $\alpha \cdot 2^n+\beta \cdot 3^n=a_n$ for all $n$.

Why we can ensure that there are no other solutions? (i.e. not the form $r^n$)

@BoweiTang, because the space of solutions has dimension 2, since two initial conditions are needed.

@lhf Get the idea, thank you.

@BoweiTang, for your information, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250234/existence-and-uniqueness-of-solutions-to-difference-equations.

@Simon Much clearer now, thanks.

@BoweiTang If you had another solution satisfying the same initial conditions, you could subtract the two solutions. The difference would satisfy the recurrence and have initial conditions zero, zero -- hence be zero.
